# Too many fillable fields in model Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have around 200 fields in a table that are numbered:

```
field_1
field_2
etc
```

I tried to insert data in table:

```
Result::insert($data);
```

Where `$data` is multiple array:

```
$data = [] = array("field_1" => 3);
$data = [] = array("field_1" => 2);
```

Can I set `*` in option `protected $fillable = ["*"];` to make all fields fillable?

Comment: Code smells all over the place. (database smells)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you need to set all columns as fillable, do this in the model:

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

> If you would like to make all attributes mass assignable, you may define the $guarded property as an empty array

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 30):

In such scenario, you can try doing the reverse. For example: `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` field as $guarded. Like:

```
protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

Except these rest will be considered as `fillable` i.e. **mass assignable**.

You can find details in [Official Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent)

> Guarding Attributes
>
> While **$fillable** serves as a "**white list**" of attributes that should be
>   mass assignable, you may also choose to use **$guarded**. The **$guarded**
>   property should contain an array of attributes that you do not want to
>   be mass assignable. All other attributes not in the array will be mass
>   assignable. So,  **$guarded** functions like a "**black list**". Of course,
>   you should use either **$fillable** or **$guarded** - not both.

Comment: Where `id` is primary key (Autoincrement)?

Comment: Yes if you are using `$table->increments('id')` in your migration file.